# Shopware 6 : how to detect any category add/update through EventSubscriberInterface on SalesChannel level?

Tags: shopware6

Does anyone knows how to check whether particular category is being added/updated/deleted in Shopware 6?

I want to use `Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface` via **Subscriber** or have to implement any other stuff?

**UPDATE**: Able to find couple of entity related events but still not able to differentiate(detect) if category is adding or modified

**plugin/src/Resources/config/services.xml**

```
<!-- ... -->
<service id="MyPlugin\MySubscriber">
    <tag name="kernel.event_subscriber"/>
</service>
<!-- ... -->
```

**MySubscriber.php**

```
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

namespace MyPlugin;

use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Shopware\Core\Content\Category\CategoryEvents;
use Shopware\Core\Content\Category\Event\CategoryIndexerEvent;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\Event\EntityDeletedEvent;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\Event\EntityWrittenEvent;

class MySubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    public static function getSubscribedEvents(): array
    {
        return [
            CategoryEvents::CATEGORY_INDEXER_EVENT => 'onCategoryIndex',
            CategoryEvents::CATEGORY_DELETED_EVENT => 'onCategoryDelete',
            CategoryEvents::CATEGORY_WRITTEN_EVENT => 'onCategoryWritten'
        ];
    }

    public function onCategoryWritten(EntityWrittenEvent $event): void
    {
        $ids = $event->getIds();    
        //how to check here whether category is adding or modified here or any other event.
        //EntityWrittenEvent in both actions(add/modify) this listener is triggering
        file_put_contents('/var/onCategoryWritten.text', print_r($ids, true), FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
    
    }

    public function onCategoryDelete(EntityDeletedEvent $event): void
    {
        $ids = $event->getIds();
        file_put_contents('/var/onCategoryDelete.text', print_r($ids, true), FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);

    }
    
    public function onCategoryIndex(CategoryIndexerEvent $event): void
    {
        $ids = $event->getIds();
        file_put_contents('/var/onCategoryIndex.text', print_r($ids, true), FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check operation which was done in write results like

```
foreach($event->getWriteResults() as $writeResult) {

    if ($writeResult->getOperation() === EntityWriteResult::OPERATION_INSERT) 
    {
        //entity created
    }
    if ($writeResult->getOperation() === EntityWriteResult::OPERATION_UPDATE) 
    {
        //entity updated/modified
    }
}
```